# How to get the current Post author URL and his display name

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show all posts from the current author of the post. Here is the code I have implemented:

```
echo '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="'.get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )'">'.the_author().'</a></h2>';
```

BTW, I'm confused regarding the single bracket. When I start with {**echo '**} then how it is possible to display this call:

```
get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )
```

as the ID parameter has both single brackets. I'm getting tons of errors and don't know how to place the author profile link in order to display all his post under his Display Name. Thanks in advance. Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call the function before and save their output to a variable, so u can just echo out the variable. But I do believe your functions do not work at all, (function inside function, passing string ID as parameter? Is that working ok?)

Im not sure how your code looks but for example:

```
$url = get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID'));
$author = the_author();

echo '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="'. $url . '">'. $author .'</a></h2>';
```

You also missed one **.** (dot) after

> get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )

Can you post your functions code?

As for the single quotes, google up Escaping quotation marks

Comment: Excuse me, there is a missing ")" in "$url = get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID');" line.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate this link, within [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), by using the [the_author_posts_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_author_posts_link/) Template Tag. For example:
[source page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates)

```
<p>Written by: 
<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></p>
```

output will look like this:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8888/siteurl/author/admin/" title="Posts by admin" rel="author">admin</a>
```